# Perturbation theory

Tags: perturbation-theory

$y''(x) + (x^2 – \epsilon x^4 )y(x) = Ey(x)$
For the above differential equation,I need to find energy eigen state using perturbation theory.

Working : I solved the  recursion relation,mainly considering anstaz relation and finally obtained
$$2j(Bn,j) = (j + 1)(2j + 1)Bn,j+1 + Bn−1,j−2 − \sum[(Bn−k,1 Bk,j,when \,n=1,k=1)$$
But I am not sure how to code on mathematica and how the plot look likes.can anyone please advice me how to proceed or how the graph would be for negative coefficient?

Comment: Any specific *kind* of perturbation theory?

Comment: This is find ten eigenstate and corresponding values until 50episilon terms and to use pade-50/50 approximation to plot graph.

Comment: What is Ey(x)? Also, it's difficult to tell what you did. Did you consider $y=y_0+\epsilon y_1+\epsilon^2 y_2+...$?

Comment: yes..I solved analytically the equation.after a long process I arrived with an recursion relation 2j(Bn,j) = (j + 1)(2j + 1)Bn,j+1 + Bn−1,j−2 − Sum[(Bn−k,1 Bk,j,when n=1,k=1).E refers to eigen energy state of harmonic oscillator

Comment: I think the equation is a one-dimensional Schrödinger stationary equation Hy = Ey, where $H=\partial_x^2+(x^2-\epsilon x^4) $ and $E\in \mathbb{R}$ a constant. This is an eigenvalue problem for the operator H. Is that correct XXXXX? Are you sure that it isn't $-y''(x)$ instead of $y''(x)$? Then it would be a more common problem, namely the a perturbed quantum harmonic oscillator. That would be an interesting problem.